# Can you change the language in MW (2019) in the digital version (PS4)

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare

So for some reason I have a Spanish storefront in my PS4 store, so I have to buy games from the Spanish storefront even though I live in the UK. (Btw, before anyone asks, I can change it to an English storefront but it doesn’t let me buy anything from it.) I can buy games from the Spanish storefront and still get the English language in it for some games. However,  I recently preordered Modern Warfare 2019, and I am worried that the game will be in Spanish and not in English. Does anyone know if you can change the language in game when you first login in when it came out?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing any defniitve statements regarding the language settings of the game. If there aren't it seems that you [can use VPNs to adjust the region and language of the game](https://www.reddit.com/r/modernwarfare/comments/d61wqu/language_change_for_beta/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if there is no language select in game, it's gonna pick the console's language.

Usually these days all the languages are on the disk or as downloadable patches, so really, I would not worry that you can't switch it to english.

Basically, if the english version exists anywhere, doesn't matter where you get your game you should be able to play in english. And well, english clearly is an existing version of the game. So you should be able to play in english wherever you got the game from.

The days where you bought a game and it was the spanish version and only that are long gone.

Comment: Millions of copy’s of modern warfare come without the desired language and there’s now way to add a language pack on PlayStation! If you bought a Italian copy you can choose from Italian and Spanish language, that’s it!

Comment: I have no way to test your problem, but it would be suprising. Usually the Original Version (English) is pretty much always available.